# Is there a built-in way to have an async method fire an event with the return data when it completes?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, events, .net-standard

Let's say I've created a library with the following async method:

```cs
public async Task<string> MyAsyncMethod()
{
    // Do stuff

    return someString;
}
```

Now let's say I want the app developer to be able to call this method in a typical fire-and-forget fashion, but then consume an event with the return data when the method completes.

If I were to do this manually, it might look something like this:

```cs
public async Task<string> MyAsyncMethod()
{
    // Do stuff

    // Fire the success event
    MyEvent?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs { Result = someString });

    return someString;
}

...

// Use this callback method to consume the event
public void C_MyAsyncMethodHasCompleted(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Async method has completed with return value: " + e.Result);
}
```

Here's my question:  Is it a waste of time to do it like this?  I.e. is there some simpler, built-in thing with C# and/or .NET that already does this?

I mainly just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel with this approach.

Comment: But async calls doesn't block the calling thread, you can simply use `var string = await MyAsyncMethod();` somewhere. Also why do you need to return `Task<string>` if there is an event inside method? It seems, that you've mixed two approaches

Comment: If you need callback, then it is not fire-and-forget. If you need callback, the simplest is to pass a delegate. Methods can implicitly work as delegates. Events are useful if you need an unbound number of callbacks. Sort of, but actually these are two different patterns. And a third one is async/await on itself. Awaiting is just splitting execution. Meanwhile, the rest of the code can run. What you described looks like a situation where you have multiple async results: notify multiple times, return once - like when updating progress on uploading a file. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

> I want the app developer to be able to call this method in a typical fire-and-forget fashion, but then consume an event with the return data when the method completes.

I think you might be over-complicating things. I think you can ignore this requirement and just let the consumer deal with it.

In it's simplest form, let's say the consumer wants to start this method, go do something else while waiting, then come back to the result later. They can do something like this:

```cs
var myTask = MyAsyncMethod();
// The method starts running and returns a Task<string> when it hits the first await
// (when it starts waiting for whatever I/O request)

DoOtherStuff();

//Now I'm ready for the result, so I await:
var theString = await myTask;
DoSomethingWith(theString);
```

Likewise, they could store a reference to the `Task<string>` however they want (pass it to another method, etc.) and only `await` it when they're ready to use the result.

Or they can use `ContinueWith` as Theodor suggests (but that has some caveats, like how exceptions are handled). Either way, you, as the author of this library, don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are searching for the [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method? The caller can create an "event" by chaining a continuation to the task:

```
Task<string> task = MyAsyncMethod();
_ = task.ContinueWith(_ => { /* Event handler */ }, TaskScheduler.Default);
```